# Why isn't my named PHP session able to be called?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've already posted something similar to this, but I redesigned the entire system. Instead of the original system I've created a separate sub domain for accounts. I'm having issues getting any variables from my named session. I'm attempting to transfer user information accross sub domains for login purposes, and tracking purposes. Anyways, here is the code.

Login Script

```
<?php
session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.ueteribus.com');
session_start();
?>
```

That code is just the bit that tells the $_SESSION to be spread across all the domains. (Or at least it is supposed to) Anyways, the LoginSession name is where the problem comes in. If that is added in then I am unable to get anything to display using my calling scripts.

Currently I use

$_SESSION['USERNAME_ueteribus']
$_SESSION['PASSWORD_ueteribus']
$_SESSION['loginsession21']

Those are the main $SESSIONS that I use, and currently I am unable to get them displayed when giving the Cookies any specific name.

This is the current script I am using to call the actual $_SESSION by name.

```
<?php
session_name('LoginSession');
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['loginsession21'];
?>
```

That worked fine before I added the custom name for the $_SESSION.

Any help would be much appreciated as this issue has been plaguing me for a very long time, also.. When I actually head into the Cookies on my browser, I see LoginSession, but it is listed under the main domain. www.XXXX.com instead of account.xxxx.com.
No idea if that is normal or not, anyways.. Any additional information can be requested, and thank you for any assistance that you can provide.

NOTE: All the scripts and code listed above are saved on the account sub domain!

UPDATE:

I just tried this code and it still doesn't work.

```
<?php
session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.ueteribus.com');
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['loginsession21'];
?>
```

Also I added this script to the top of each page.

```
<?php

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'ueteribus.com');
session_start();

?>
```

Comment: I've always been told the exact opposite, and I actually found that script on this website and it was listed that way.. But, I'll try it out.

Comment: Actually.. I just switched it around and changed it so that the Session name and what not was below session_start and it seemed to work. TILL I checked the Cookies, it worked because it was saving the cookies on that sub domain only, and therefore it is worthless to me. It wasn't reading the name, or the properties. So you must need to declare them before it starts.

Comment: Why do you have a dot in `'.ueteribus.com'` ? curious

Comment: Props to @Fred-ii- I wasn't seeing it for a long time either.

Comment: Apparently that is another thing that is required. You figure the domain fills the rest.. So.. Carnal is the sub domain, but you need the . before the actual domain.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing at first.. I've messed with this so many times, it isn't even funny.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/session_name) - *"you need to call `session_name()` for every request (and before `session_start()` or `session_register()` are called)"*

Comment: Funny, I ran some tests of my own, and in having `session_start();` after naming a session, `var_dump'ing` came out NULL. @Phil

Comment: @user2994429 You need to make sure that `session.auto_start` is disabled in your `php.ini` and you also need to call `session_set_cookie_params()` for each request (just like you do for `session_name()`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) - *"you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called."*

Comment: I've already tried that as well.. It just doesn't want to work, and also.. I cannot touch my php.ini because my hosting company has not given me permission. I've already asked for it.

Comment: @user2994429 `auto_start` probably isn't on (it's disabled by default) but it would be something to check via `phpinfo()`

Comment: So how would I manage that?

Comment: @user2994429 Make a single page with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and check the results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41498/discussion-between-user2994429-and-phil)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You might want to know that the problem was in fact due to calling `session_start()` **before** `session_name()`. All session configuration **must** be done before the session is started.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I appreciate the follow-up. @Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing the session cookie config in your other (not *Login Script*) files. Just like `session_name()`, you need to call it on every request and **before** `session_start()` (despite what other commenters may believe).

```
<?php
session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.ueteribus.com');
session_start();

// of course this line will only work if you've previously set the "loginsession21" key
echo $_SESSION['loginsession21'];
?>
```

#### Update

After making changes to either session name or cookie params, you'll need to clear out the old cookie from your browser.

You also need to make sure that the session is not started **anywhere else** in your code.

I would suggest moving all the session config stuff into a single file and include it at the top of every requestable page. Also remove any and all other calls to `session_start()`.

```
<?php
// session_config.php

session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.ueteribus.com');
session_start();
```

then, in some other script

```
<?php
// some_other_script.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/session_config.php';
```

Comment: So I should add just a simple <?php
    include('../init.php');
?>

Comment: @user2994429 I'd get it working first, then centralise the configuration

Comment: @user2994429 I've updated my answer. It's also handy to enable `display_errors` while developing with `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`